# Ant can't turn on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

I use `Ant` to perform some actions like `turn tomcat off`,`compile classes in WEB-INF/classes` and then `turning on tomcat`.

This is my `build.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="jspbook" default="build" basedir=".">

<target name="build">
<echo>Starting build </echo>

<!-- Turn Tomcat Off -->
<antcall target="tomcatOff"/>

<!-- Compile Everything-->
<antcall target="compile"/>

<!-- Turn Tomcat On -->
<antcall target="tomcatOn"/>

<echo>Build Finished </echo>
</target>


<target name="tomcatOff">
   <echo>Turning off tomcat </echo>

   <exec executable="bash" os="Windows">
       <arg value="../../bin/shutdown.bat"/>
   </exec>

   <exec executable="bash" os="Linux">
       <arg value="../../bin/shutdown.sh"/>
   </exec>
</target>


<target name="tomcatOn">
   <echo>Starting tomcat </echo>

   <exec executable="bash" os="Windows">
       <arg value="../../bin/startup.bat"/>
   </exec>

   <exec executable="bash" os="Linux">
       <arg value="../../bin/startup.sh"/>
   </exec>
</target>

<target name="compile">
   <echo>Compiling Book's Examples</echo>

<javac
   srcdir="WEB-INF/classes"
   extdirs="WEB-INF/lib:../.../common/lib"
   classpath="../../common/lib/servlet.jar"
   deprecation="yes"
   verbose="no">
   <include name="com/jspbook/**"/>

</javac>

</target>
```

When i run `ant` in `.../tomcat/webapps/jspbook/` in command line, this is result:

[image]

It looks every thing is ok, but when i try to `127.0.0.1:8080` i can't connect to tomcat.

And i have to turn tomcat handy, by `startup.bat`.

Comment: Are you spawning tomcat as a child process of ant, which then exits, taking out its child processes? Or are you starting it as a service?

Comment: Do you really have `bash` available on Windows? I think what you want is `<exec executable="../../bin/startup.bat" />`. There are lots of other improvements I want to suggest, but let's just start with that one.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I don't know what is `bash` at all, i write this code from the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use a UNIX shell to execute a Windows batch file. You want to do this instead:

```
<target name="tomcatOn">
  <echo>Starting tomcat </echo>

  <exec executable="../../bin/startup.bat" os="Windows">
  </exec>
</target>
```

(Make a similar change to the `tomcatOff` target.)

If you are always on Windows, I wouldn't even bother with the `Linux` configuration. (Besides, you can execute shell scripts directly without invoking `bash`, anwyay).

Consider using `catalina.bat` with the `start` argument directly instead of calling `startup.bat`. You will have better control over the JVM process that way.

Also consider trying to determine the path to `startup.bat` in a better way... the use of `../../bin` implies that you will always be in a certain set of directories and your script will not work outside of them.